# Show/Hide after a div created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this code to show/display `Edit` link when mouse hovers over the `start` div. This div however can be created dynamically and when it's created the code below doesn't work.

```
$(".start").hover(
        function() {
            timeclock.utils.displayEdit(this)
        },
        function() {
            timeclock.utils.hideEdit(this)
        });
```

I tried the code below but it doesn't work and it looks wrong. How can I implement `$(document).on('hover'.....)` to hide/show the `Edit` link as shown above?

```
$(document).on("hover", ".start",
        function() {
            timeclock.utils.displayEdit(this)
        },
        function() {
            timeclock.utils.hideEdit(this)
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried setting up mouseenter and mouseleave with the .on() method instead of hover?  The syntax for .hover() is fine, but it can only target existing elements.  The .on() method can target elements that haven't been created yet, which is useful - but it requires a specific syntax to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hover()` is a shortcut for binding `mouseenter` and `mouseout` handlers. Your second example doesn't work because `on()` doesn't take two functions like that. You bind multiple handlers at once using delegated events like this:

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        timeclock.utils.displayEdit(this);    
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        timeclock.utils.hideEdit(this);
    }
}, '.start');
```

Simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/TRcR9/

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is a little off. You can attach multiple event handlers simultaneously using a plain object.

```
$(document).on({
  mouseenter: function(){
    timeclock.utils.displayEdit(this);
  },
  mouseleave: function(){
    timeclock.utils.hideEdit(this);
  }
}, ".start");
```

I've created a Codepen example here: http://cdpn.io/dDewi

Comment: This use of .on() isn't delegated, so if .start doesn't exist yet, it won't be applied.  That doesn't make this approach wrong, it just has to be used with care.

Comment: That's a good point @SurrealDreams, what about wrapping in a document.ready function?

Comment: Document ready ensures that static elements of the page have loaded, but doesn't help with creating dynamic elements.  You could always attach the event handlers right after .start is appended to the page, then you are guaranteed to have the target.

Comment: Cool, thanks @SurrealDreams, I've edited based on your comments. I think the syntax in OPs code was just off.

Comment: The "start" selector needs a "." - it should be ".start".  And it needs a handler for mouseleave.

Comment: Yeah damn me for trying to edit so many times so quickly! Haha, beaten to the punch again. Thanks @SurrealDreams

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 errors in your code.
1. you should use $(this) instead of this. There is a different between this two.
2. you have to bind the hover again whenever a new div is created.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you have is a a little off.  Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sqb4g/3/) with a working example:

HTML:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#edit { display: none; }
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on(
        {
            mouseenter: function() 
            {
                $('#edit').show();
            },
            mouseleave: function()
            {
                $('#edit').hide();
            }
        },
        '.start'
    );   

    $('#container').prepend('<div class="start">Mouse over me <a id="edit" href="#">edit</a></div>');
});
```

Comment: In your code `Edit` link isn't accessible. It hides itself too quickly

Comment: Thanks u54r...I updated my answer so the edit link doesn't hide when you try to click it.